# How to access attribut from one class to another class in PyQt5 / PySide2

Tags: python, class, pyqt5, pyside2

I cannot get access to attribut **self.horizontalLayout_Base** in class **Ui_MainWindow**  where I want add new widgets.

There is :

1. Main class **MainWindow** which inherits class **Ui_MainWindow**.
2. Class **Ui_MainWindow** creates layout.
3. Class **Dialog** provides additional information and confirmation or cancellation.

Main class **MainWindow** calls class **Dialog**. Class **Dialog** is queried and then the method **tableWidget** in class **MainWindow** is called. But there is not access to attribut **self.horizontalLayout_Base** which was creating by class **Ui_MainWindow**.

Is there any way to get access?

**Main class MainWindow**

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, obj=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        ...
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        ...
        
        
    def tableWidget(self):
        if len(list) > 0:
            row = len(list)
            clmn = len(list[0]) 
            self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(row, clmn + 1)
        else:
            return
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        ...

        Ui_MainWindow.gridLayout_Base.addLayout(self.vbox) # Here I want to get access
```

**Layout class Ui_MainWindow**

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1110, 772)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.horizontalLayout_Base = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout() # This is target

        ...
```

**Class Dialog**

```
class Dialog(QDialog):

    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self, souradnice):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        ...

    def buttonAccepted(self):
        ...

        MainWindow.tableWidget(self)
        self.close()
```

Comment: If you want to add a QTableWidget, then why are you creating a layout?

Comment: it's an additional widget based on the event

Comment: Sorry but your answer doesn't make a lot of sense. Widgets and layouts are two completely different things.

Comment: additional widgets are created with the QTableWidget in layout, and this "package" in vbox layout I need to put to Ui_MainWindow.gridLayout_Base.addLayout(self.vbox).

Comment: For future reference, if you just want to share parts of your code, that might be fine, but only as long as the remaining make sense. Providing a minimal [reproducible] example doesn't mean to share as few code as possible, because we cannot know everything you left out, which could make reading your code confusing. "Minimal" means that you should give us the minimal code required for anybody to read and understand what your code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're confusing what classes, instances and their methods are (for this, I strongly suggest you to do some research, as they are fundamental aspects of OOP and cannot be ignored).

In `tableWidget` you cannot access `gridLayout_Base` from `Ui_MainWindow`, because that's a class. Since you're both inheriting from QMainWindow *and* Ui_MainWindow, and you're calling `setupUi(self)` that means that all attributes of the ui are actually created as attribute members of the **instance**, so you can access the layout just by using `self.gridLayout_Base`.
Then, if you're adding a layout, you must use `addLayout()`, not `addWidget()` (which is for widgets only).

```
    def tableWidget(self):
        # ...
        self.gridLayout_Base.addLayout(self.vbox)
```

Then, I don't know how you're creating and opening the dialog, but you certainly cannot call `MainWindow.tableWidget(self)`: that would result in calling that method with the *dialog* instance as first argument (self), so you won't be adding anything to the main window.

A better and safer way (which is also the commonly accepted practice) is to show the dialog as modal by calling its `exec()`, and then react to it according to the result. In order to correcty achieve this, you should not call `self.close()` on the dialog (which results in *rejecting* it) but [`self.accept()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept).

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    # ...
    def someFunctionToShowDialog(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        if dialog.exec_():
            parameters = dialog.getValues()
            self.tableWidget()
            self.doSomethingWithParameters(parameters)


class Dialog(QDialog):
    # ...
    def buttonAccepted(self):
        self.accept()

    def getValues(self):
        return self.someValue, self.anotherValue
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. 
When I do ```dialog = Dialog(self)``` Dialog open another one. 
And when I write ```self.gridLayout_Base.addLayout(self.vbox)``` then:
**AttributeError: 'Dialog' object has no attribute 'gridLayout_Base'**
I try to show the code..

Comment: @Pr.Syn as said, I don't know how you're creating the dialog, so read my code and try to understand what it does. About the second error, that means that you're trying to call `tableWidget` *from* the dialog (which doesn't make sense) or you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: thanks, I got it...I was stuck and I didn't see the possibility, but thanks to you, I found a solution.